# Create Google spreadsheet as template and duplicate the column to block using python

Tags: python, google-sheets

Using python I was able to access google spreadsheet. How to duplicate block of columns, into the set of block of columns and keeping the same format.

For Example: Use rack layout and copy the block of columns into next available column and then populate data base on the certain rows.

[image: template]

Image in Right is the template and left is populate data.

I tried using below code to fetch the current setting but didn't work.

```
from gspread_formatting import *
rules = get_user_entered_format(sheet_instance, "A:D")
pprint(rules)
userdata = get_default_format(sheet)
pprint(userdata)
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your sample image and your script. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, it seems that `sheet_instance` and `sheet` are not declared. How about this?

Comment: Hello @tanaike apologized if I was not able to clear the issue. I would like to generate rack elevation base on the provide data: 
How many racks: 4, which going in loop to copy the template from range (A:D) keeping intact format. then add data. 
Trying to generate dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to copy the cells "A:G" including the cell format. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in your situation, do you want to copy them to another sheet in the same Spreadsheet? Or, do you want to copy them to a sheet in the different Spreadsheet?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike That is correct! As "A:G" is just a template of the format which I like to maintain and copy to next available column. So for example, If I want to generate 4 times, it should copy same format from template A:G to 4 times. Then I would like update the racks with devices, by given Rack# and RU location.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `That is correct!`, I could understand that you wanted to copy the cells "A:G" including the cell format. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand whether you want to copy them to another sheet in the same Spreadsheet or you want to copy them to a sheet in the different Spreadsheet.

Comment: It will be copy into another sheet, apologize, I didn't answer your question. There is sheet call "RackTemplate" which is A:G will be in a format. Depending how many racks needs to generate, it will copy into another sheet, lets say "sheet2". Then add the object like I show into the snapshot, "Update Rack1"

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, is your process running between 2 sheets under one Google Spreadsheet? And, in order to correctly confirm your format of the cells, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?